# How can I match elements one-to-one?

Tags: java, android

I have a Recyclerview and there are Imageviews in it. When I click any of image, I want to make visible a number of information about image on the image.

Well, I did it but it seems everything's happening randomly... When I click first image, informations appearing on the second, when I click on the second its working normally and when I click third, nothing happening etc.

Here is some of my code;

```
@Override
public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recycler_item, parent, false);

    myViewHolder = new MyViewHolder(view);

    myViewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
       if (isUp) {
           slideDown(myViewHolder.infoView);
       } else {
           slideUp(myViewHolder.infoView);
       }
           isUp = !isUp;
       }
    });

return myViewHolder;
}

class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    ImageView imageView;

    public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
       super(itemView);
       init();
    }

    void init() {
       imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewID);
       ...
    }
}
```

It seems I should group some elements or is there any better idea, way ?

Slide method;

```
// slide the view from below itself to the current position
public void slideUp(View view) {
    view.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    infoView.animate().alpha(1.0f).setDuration(500);
    ScaleAnimation animate = new ScaleAnimation(
            1f, 1f, // Start and end values for the X axis scaling
            0f, 1f, // Start and end values for the Y axis scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0f, // Pivot point of X scaling
            Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 1f);                // toYDelta
    animate.setDuration(800);
    animate.setFillAfter(true);
    view.startAnimation(animate);
}
```

I moved onClickListener method to onBindViewHolder and thats what make sense but result did not change.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.textView_name.setText(nameElement.get(position).text());
    Picasso.get().load(imageElement.get(position).absUrl("src")).fit().into(holder.imageView);

    holder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (isUp) {
                myViewHolder.slideDown(myViewHolder.infoView);
            } else {
                myViewHolder.slideUp(myViewHolder.infoView);
            }
            isUp = !isUp;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add slideUp slideDown methods in **MyViewHolder** class

and I think no need to implement click listener in onBindViewHolder, just put it in the init function.

```
   void init() {                                                          
       imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewID);               
       imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {          
           @Override                                                      
           public void onClick(View v) {                                  
               if (isUp) {                                                
                   slideDown(v);                                          
               } else {                                                   
                   slideUp(v);                                            
               }                                                          
               isUp = !isUp;                                              
           }                                                              
       });                                                                
   }
```

hope it works!!!

Comment: I've tried it exactly but nothing changed. I already have onBindViewHolder method in my Recycler. But I'm confused about using slideDown(myViewHolder.infoView); or slideDown(holder.infoView); And where should I define my infoView ? In recycler class or holder class ?

Comment: hi, actually i don't know about your slideDown,SlideUp method. could you post that method aswell?

Comment: its just running animation and changing visibility, please check edit.

Comment: Also where should be defined these methods also ? :)

Comment: hi, I updated the answer. please check it and let me know, I am waiting for your response

Comment: I LOVE YOU. But how and why ? :D Can you explain the logic ?

Comment: Happy to hear it working, for the listeners, it is enough to implement it once. Therefore implement it inside the MyViewHolder class is enough. and still, I have no idea about "myViewHolder.infoView"

Comment: Hi, Your current problem is a little bit confusing and I am unable to understanding. Can you start a new question with full of your code and explanation of the problem?

Comment: Solved. I defined isUp = false inside onBindViewHolder method. So whenever I change tab or slide recycler, it will always start over. Ty so much again and again.

Answer (score 0):

You should add listener for the ViewHolder in `onBindViewHolder`, and not `onCreateViewHolder`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's better to define `onClickListener` in `onBindViewHolder`
Second, store the data on a POJO class, and save last states,
 so you can keep the last state of an item(isUP or !)

for example, you have this model:

```
class ImageModel {

  private String imageURI;
  private Boolean isUP ; 
  //getter setters
}
```

then if you pass a list of ImageModel into your adapter, you can easily change the `isUP`

and on your adapter change the state of imageviews based on `isUP`

```
   if (model.isUp) {
       slideDown(myViewHolder.infoView);
   } else {
       slideUp(myViewHolder.infoView);
   }
```